# How to submit form using AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have an event listener:

```
$('button.publish').live('click', function() {
    //enter code here
});
```

This `button` element is inside a form. I know that I can't use `$(this).submit();` 'cause it will cause refresh. I also can't target the form by its ID because I'm trying to make it for general use (add news, add contact, add ...).

Knowing this, I can use the form's action for this is different from each other but I don't know how to submit the form inside the button event listener using AJAX (using `$.post()`).

Is this the correct use:

```
var form = $(this).closest('form');
$.post(form.attr('action'), form.serializeArray(), callback, type);
```

Or there is a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is correct, you can use [`.serliaze()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to save a few steps on the jQuery side, like this:

```
var form = $(this).closest('form');
$.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(), function(data) {
  alert("The response was: " + data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know an advanced way, but a simple way is to get each form element's data like with $("#bar").val(); quick example:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: data: "bar="+$("#bar").val()+"&foo=bar",
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });
```